# UITextView gradient layer apply not working

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview, cagradientlayer

I want to apply gradient layer on top 10% and bottom 10% of UITextView. To do this, I place a dummy UIView called container view and make UITextView a subview of it. And then I add the following code:

```
   if let containerView = textView.superview {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer(layer: containerView.layer)
        gradient.frame = containerView.bounds
        gradient.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
        gradient.locations = [0.0, 0.1, 0.9, 1.0]
        containerView.layer.mask = gradient
    }
```

But the gradient is only applied to the top, not the bottom. Is there something wrong with the code?

Further, if I resize the container view anytime by modifying it's constraints, do I need to edit the mask layer every time?

Edit: Here is the output from @DonMag answer.

[image]

But what I want is something like in this image that text fades at the bottom.

[image]

EDIT2:

Here are screenshots after DonMag's revised answer.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DongMag solution is very complicated. Instead, you just need a mask implemented like:

```
@IBDesignable
class MaskableLabel: UILabel {
    var maskImageView = UIImageView()

    @IBInspectable
    var maskImage: UIImage? {
        didSet {
            maskImageView.image = maskImage
            updateView()
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        updateView()
    }

    func updateView() {
        if maskImageView.image != nil {
            maskImageView.frame = bounds
            mask = maskImageView
        }
    }
}
```

Then with a simple gradient mask [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhIJH.png), You can see it even right in the storyboard.

[image: Preview]

<sub>**Note**: You can use this method and replace `UILabel` with any other view you like to subclass.</sub>

Here is **[the example project on the GitHub](https://github.com/MojtabaHs/Masking-With-Gradient)**

Comment: I need it in UITextView, not label

Comment: Do as the note said. Just change the `UILabel` to `UITextView`. It supports all `UIView` subclasses.

Comment: I have updated my answer to match your need. As you can see, no changes needed except for that `UILabel` to `UITextView`. Just one word in the code ;)

Comment: I think the image needs to be applied to container view of UITextView, not UITextView. And the problem with image is it needs to be a different one if you need to customize height of gradient.

Comment: The code also crashes on autorotation "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" on line  maskImageView.frame = bounds

Comment: I have added the example project to the GitLab and post the link at the end of my answer. I can't see any issues.

Comment: Ok in my setup I used your maskable view code to make subview of UIView which is container view. Then I added UITextView to it.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** - after clarification of desired effect...

My initial answer as to why you were only seeing the gradient on the top stands:

> You're only seeing the gradient on the top because you gave it ***four*** locations but only ***two*** colors.

So, now that you provided an image of what you're trying to do...

Use this `DoubleGradientMaskView` as the "container" view for the text view:

```
class DoubleGradientMaskView: UIView {
    
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.1, 0.9, 1.0]
        layer.mask = gradientLayer
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    }
    
}
```

---

Example controller:

```
class GradientTextViewViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let textView = UITextView()
    let containerView = DoubleGradientMaskView()
    let bkgImageView = UIImageView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [bkgImageView, textView, containerView].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        bkgImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        if let img = UIImage(named: "background") {
            bkgImageView.image = img
        } else {
            bkgImageView.backgroundColor = .blue
        }
        
        view.addSubview(bkgImageView)
        view.addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(textView)
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // add an image view so we can see the white text
            bkgImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bkgImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bkgImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            bkgImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // constraint text view inside container
            textView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor),
            
            // constrain container Top / Bottom 40, Leading / Trailing 40
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -40.0),

        ])
        
        textView.isScrollEnabled = true
        
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 48.0, weight: .bold)
        textView.textColor = .white
        textView.backgroundColor = .clear

        textView.text = String((1...20).flatMap { "This is row \($0)\n" })
        
    }

}
```

---

Result:

[image]

or, with a blue background instead of an image:

[image]

---

You're only seeing the gradient on the top because you gave it ***four*** locations but only ***two*** colors.

Changing the colors to:

```
gradient.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor]
```

would probably give you the appearance you want... but you'd need additional code to handle size changing.

If you use this class as your "container" view, sizing will be automatic:

```
class DoubleGradientView: UIView {
    
    var gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer!
    
    override class var layerClass: AnyClass {
        return CAGradientLayer.self
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        gradientLayer = self.layer as? CAGradientLayer
        gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.black.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.clear.cgColor, UIColor.black.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 0.1, 0.9, 1.0]
    }
    
}
```

Here is an example controller. It creates two "text views in containers."

- The top one is scrollable, with a height of 100.
- The bottom one is NOT scrollable, so it will size its height to the text as you type.

Both are constrained Leading / Trailing at 60-pts, so you'll also see the automatic gradient update when you rotate the device.

```
class GradientBehindTextViewViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let textView1 = UITextView()
    let containerView1 = DoubleGradientView()

    let textView2 = UITextView()
    let containerView2 = DoubleGradientView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [textView1, containerView1, textView2, containerView2].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        }
        
        containerView1.addSubview(textView1)
        view.addSubview(containerView1)
        
        containerView2.addSubview(textView2)
        view.addSubview(containerView2)
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constraint text view inside container
            textView1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView1.topAnchor),
            textView1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView1.leadingAnchor),
            textView1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView1.trailingAnchor),
            textView1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView1.bottomAnchor),

            // constrain container Top + 40, Leading / Trailing 80
            containerView1.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            containerView1.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 80.0),
            containerView1.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -80.0),

            // text view 1 will have scrolling enabled, so we'll set its height to 100
            containerView1.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100.0),
            
            // constraint text view inside container
            textView2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView2.topAnchor),
            textView2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView2.leadingAnchor),
            textView2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView2.trailingAnchor),
            textView2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView2.bottomAnchor),
            
            // constrain container2 Top to container1 bottom + 40, Leading / Trailing 80
            containerView2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView1.bottomAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            containerView2.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 80.0),
            containerView2.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -80.0),
            
            // text view 2 will NOT scroll (it will size with the text) so no height / bottom

        ])
        
        // text view 1 should scroll
        textView1.isScrollEnabled = true
        
        // text view 1 should NOT scroll we want the text view to size itelf as we type
        textView2.isScrollEnabled = false
        
        // let the gradient show through
        textView1.backgroundColor = .clear
        textView2.backgroundColor = .clear

        textView1.text = "Initial text for text view 1."
        textView2.text = "Initial text for text view 2."

    }
    
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think the container view should not be UITextView. May be I worded the question incorrectly, but my intent was to have top 10% and bottom 10% of UITextView frame (as opposed to bounds) to have gradient. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: In my answer, the container **is** a `UIView` subclass...

Comment: I see that, but what is the role of textView2? Does it exists only because we don't know text height in advance so it will take care of scenario where text height is less than 100?

Comment: Did you examine the code? And did you try running it? Two examples: one with a fixed-height scrolling text view, the other with a non-scrolling auto-sizing text view.

Comment: I reviewed as well as tried your code. See the output image in the question. Do not understand the purpose of textView2.

Comment: @DeepakSharma - ***delete*** everything related to `textView2` and `containerView2`. That was simply a ***second example*** - using a self-sizing text view instead of a fixed-height text view.

Comment: Ok I also posted a sample image of the effect I want. I need a fading text effect which is not what is achieved through your code,

Comment: I think the effect I want will be achieved only by applying a mask.

Comment: @DeepakSharma - would have been very helpful if you had explained and/or shown an image of the effect you were going for in your initial question. See my **Edit** at the top of my answer.

Comment: Sorry, but the effect is not exactly what was there in the question. See EDIT 2 in the question.